# Propel Inheritance: generate only children tables

Tags: inheritance, orm, propel

In [Concrete Inheritance](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/09-inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance), is it possible to mark parent as abstract and have NO table generated for it?

For instance:

- Abstract A
- B extends A
- C extends A

› That would generate all 3 classes (one abstract), but only 2 tables (table B and table C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [skipSql](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/schema.html#table-element) on table definition:

```
<table name="abstract_a" idMethod="native" skipSql="true">
...
</table>
```